# Additional props on abstract field are ignored

Tags: typescript

I expect to see an error from TS when I add props to a type, when those props are not part of their interface.

This works OK if you deal with the interface directly but seems to only work for required fields when type is coming from an abstract class.

Why is this? And how can I get the validation to work as expected?

```
interface IProps {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

abstract class AbstractClass {
  protected abstract props: IProps;
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  protected props = {
    foo: "hello", 
    bar: 2,
    baz: true // <--- Why am I not getting 'baz' does not exist in type 'IProps'?
  };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAOBnZAbwChlkYssAuZPMKUAcwG5TkAjOKGkAVwFt20VgF9ixOOzpREYZAgA2cPAQCCU+rIDCSlUTY5skBJAAmySdNnJDuPDQzZ8o8YuUEtWEAigRIO92QIAA9IEFM1DRkTAL0SMgQvaV4TLCgACgBKfTIyPF4caCzWMjEDIwgTCHNbfGQAXhzcimpkACIACwgFBSw2gBpkNjJObmQAJn7hjjgALxp6XhQAemXkAB4AWm3kAHUOgE8LfjRkECw5Rj8wJmQAck5Zu+RTLAgCc7kQ4DpkUGQwAdCvdHHY7gB+NgiURAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the inferred type of `props` in `ConcreteClass` is a subinterface of `IProps` that includes `baz`. You can assign subinterface instances (and subclass instances) to variables declared with supertypes, just not the other way around (because the other way around, they're missing properties).

To prevent that, you need to use the type name again:

```
class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  protected props: IProps = {
  // *** Here -----^
      foo: "hello", 
      bar: 2,
      baz: true // Error: Type '{ foo: string; bar: number; baz: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IProps'.
  };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAOBnZAbwChlkYssAuZPMKUAcwG5TkAjOKGkAVwFt20VgF9ixOOzpREYZAgA2cPAQCCU+rIDCSlUTY5skBJAAmySdNnJDuPDQzZ8o8YuUEtWEAigRIO92QIAA9IEFM1DRkTAL0SMgQvaV4TLCgACgBKfTIyPF4caCzWMjEyW2MzGyd7NEw7ZABeHOQAelbkACpu5AAJaBQAWmHhgD02XPJKGgAiAAsIBQUsGYAaZAnczm5kACZVzbJOAC8ael4UduQAUShsHYAVAE9C5AByQinqWnomZg4uDwBEIoP8TjR2JQFBA4CB-iI3shgAQQFg5O5gIwQJJocgwFg8S8UG9HHY3gA6NgiURAA)

It's different from doing this:

```
let props: IProps;
// ...
props = {
    foo: "hello", 
    bar: 2,
    baz: true // Error: Type '{ foo: string; bar: number; baz: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IProps'.
};
```

...because `ConcreteClass` is *declaring* `props`, not assigning to something that already exists.

Alternately, you could define `props` as non-`abstract`. It's a bit of a pain because you have to initialize it with appropriate defaults. You *could* declare it as `IProps|undefined` to avoid that:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
  protected props: IProps|undefined = undefined;
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.props = {
        foo: "hello", 
        bar: 2,
        baz: true // Error: Type '{ foo: string; bar: number; baz: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IProps'.
    };
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAOBnZAbwChlkYssAuZPMKUAcwG5TkAjOKGkAVwFt20VgF9ixOOzpREYZAgA2cPAQCCU+rIDCSlUTY5skBJAAmyQ7jw0M2fAB9eIUxBigI5gLzInLtyA9RcUVlAi0sEAQoCEgdUOQIAA9IZzUNGRM4vRIyBAjpXhMsKAAKAEp9MjI8XhxoctYq5DAAC2A8ADpLfGRvHKaqimpkACIWiAUFLBGAGmQ2AY4uGgAmGYWBzgAvGnpeFAB6A+QAUShsbmQAFQBPOuQAckJyShppJmYly75BYSWdjiUBQQOAgT4iB7IdrIEBYOShYCMECSYHNLDNO4oB62KwPDobESNZBiERAA)

...or of course just initialize it with appropriate defaults and then overwrite them if/as necessary:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
  protected props: IProps = {
      foo: "",
      bar: 42
  }
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.props.foo = "hello";
    this.props.bar = 2;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAOBnZAbwChlkYssAuZPMKUAcwG5TkAjOKGkAVwFt20VgF9ixOOzpREYZAgA2cPAQCCU+rIDCSlUTY5skBJAAmyQ7jw0M2fMgC8+si-KUaAIg8AaNq87cyAAsAExsYmLEisoEWlggCFAQkDoxyBAAHpAgpmoaMiapeiRkCPHSvCZYUAAUAJTOLni8OND1rK5gABbAeAB0lvh9FFiOyB5dEAoKWB4dLt29A3b9AWMh8xFAA)